# Change the model in build.prop

Tags: android

I would change the name of the model programmatically and I have root permissions, but my code does not work well and do not understand the problem.
The second toast give me this message "Error2:File/system/build.prop/ro.product.model open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)"
code:

```
 try {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
    os.writeBytes("mount -o remount rw /system/\n"); 
    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    os.flush();
    process.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error1: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    File file=new File("/system/build.prop/ro.product.model");

    try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    String content = "xx";
    byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
    while (fis.read(input) != -1) {}
    content += new String(input);
    DataOutputStream outstream= new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file,false));
    String body = content;
    outstream.write(body.getBytes());
    outstream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error2: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line `FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("/system/build.prop/ro.product.model");` by:

```
FileInputStream fis = FileInputStream(file);
```

for security reasons `openFileInput` is not allowed to accept seperators in the file name. But you can create a File with seperators in the path and create a FileImputStream from the file.

Comment: thank you but give me this error: The method openFileInput(String) in the type ContextWrapper is not applicable for the arguments (File)

Comment: don't use `openFileInput`. use `FileInputStream` instead. `FileInputSteam` is applicable to take a file: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream(java.io.File)

Comment: yes i have change it but now give me  "The method FileInputStream(File) is undefined for the type MainActivity"

Comment: put your file you created into the constructor ( `new File("/system/build.prop/ro.product.model")`)  not your Activity.

Comment: I have update my Question and now the toast give me this message "Error2:File/system/build.prop/ro.product.model open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)"

Answer (score 0):

There is another problem in your porgram, the model name is not located in a file called "/system/build.prop/ro.product.model", but is defined by the line "ro.product.model=" in the file "/system/build.prop".. Be careful when editing this file!!